# LaTeX PDF compiles well but the printer fails

Tags: fonts, printing, embedding

I'm compiling a bunch of documents in LaTeX (PdfTex) with TexStudio in a Macbook Pro (MacOS Yosemite) and the compiling results appearance it's ok. The problem is I sent that documents and the receivers told me that when they printed the documents in physical format seem corrupted.
I was searching at Google and I think is about in Mac, LaTeX uses defaults fonts and these fonts are commercial. Another problem could be that the editor doesn't embed that fonts. I tried the solutions given by the community (this community, stack overflow...) but that solutions were set by default in my LaTeX configuration.

How could I find a solution to compile my LaTeX documents embedding fonts and make them available to print without text corruption? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: LaTeX does not use system fonts unless you explicitly tell it to. And all modern LaTeX installations embed the fonts in the PDF commercial or not. So as mentioned already, please post a minimal example and more information about your LaTeX installation and explicitly which programmes you use to print and on what type of printer you are printing.

Comment: BTW: can we see one of those files that the receivers refused?

Comment: It happens to all simple documents, for example \documentclass{article} and a \begin\end{document} with a simple text.

Comment: if you have the pdffonts command line application show the output from pdffonts on your pdf file (in a code block in the question)

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Are you trying to use some special fonts in your document? How are you typesetting your file; i.e., pdflatex?